# Kafka producer getting disconnected after some time with error node -1 diconnected?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

We have to publish messages to our Kafka broker, I am receiving messages every 2 sec from a service.
So I created a producer in Java, and I am using that producer throughout my application, Like whenever I need to send a message I am reusing the same producer,

```
public void sendMessage(String topic, String message) {
        L.debug(String.format("Sending %s: %s", topic, message));
        ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, message);
        kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<>(configProperties);
        kafkaProducer.send(producerRecord);
        kafkaProducer.flush();
    }
```

```
    private KafkaProducer<String, String> connect() {
        kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<>(configProperties);
        return kafkaProducer;
    }
```

Connection to Kafka is successful with and without SSL, And the producer also starts sending data to my Kafka topics, But after some time it gets disconnected with the message node -1 disconnected, from there, I have to restart the application to recreate the connection.

The error I get after some time:

[image: The error I get after some time]

I created the Kafka producer and made topics in Kafka, I thought it was due to SSL so I set up SSL on my Kafka and was able to connect with SSL as well but still, the issue was the same after some time my producer gets disconnected.

I am using the following Kafka dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Please let me know if what I am missing and also if there is a way to resolve this, or if i can catch this issue and reconnect my producer.

If i create a new producer for every message i send it works fine but I want to reuse same producer instead of creating new producer every 2 Seconds.

Thanks in advance.